# Scoped Exports in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

Once we `export` something in`JS`. For instance, in a file called `foo.js` we have a line that says::

`export default foo;`

We can import it globally from any file we want. But what if there is a need to avoid it.

Here's a problem statement:

- Consider that `X` is an application having modules `A` and `B` in it.
- Each module `A` and `B` contains a file `parser.js` which has some exported functions with the same name.
- Assume that `A` and `B` are independent modules.
- If `A` and `B` are independent modules, in principle, the modules shouldn't have access to the functions/functionalities outside their scope.
- Due to the exports being globally available, while developing, one has access to the functions in both `parser.js` files and he/she may unknowingly use the wrong piece of code.

Is there a way to define a scope to where exported modules can only be used up to a certain level.

If not, then are there any creative ways to go around the problem?

Looking for ideas to ease development problems/experience at scale :)

Comment: Given that you have to explicitly import the functions from these files using their file paths, doesn't that make it relatively clear?

Comment: True, their file paths are different. I'm trying to derive an analogy with the development experience of accessing the properties of an object. If I am using an object, all its properties are available (which are accessible). I'm wondering if there is a way to implement a similar dependency behavior using `exports`. Somewhat like namespacing?

Comment: A module is itself already a namespace. As mentioned in the answer, maybe you're looking for `import * as foo from "mod.js";` to assign a clear name to a whole module?

Comment: yeah, i think that might work. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use aliasing to avoid a naming conflict:

```
import {
  foo,
} from './some/path';

import {
  foo as bar,
} from './some/other/path';
```

But yes, most libraries have a single entry point (typically index.js) that exports the functionality of the sub-modules, and all you have to do is not export the module you want hidden. Now certainly, someone could still import the sub-module you want hidden directly by specifying a path to it in the node_modules folder, but someone doing that is a) foolishly relying on a non-public API and b) probably playing at a high enough level to avoid that kind of mistake.

As for application code consumed directly, just either wrap it in a library you add to package.json from e.g. a git url, or simply comment the code or change the name. Typescript can also help, if the functions have different type signatures it won't be possible to use one where you meant the other.

But in the end, the simplest path is to just have a little faith in your fellow developers: way, way, way too much effort goes in to trying to prevent people from making mistakes they are unlikely to make.

### EDIT based on comment

Imports can be namespaced like so:

```
import * as Whatever from 'some-module';

Whatever.someFn();
```

Comment: True, but I wonder why javascript doesn't allow namespacing imports.

Comment: hmm. makes sense :)